# Finding city, country, company name from a tweet text using Java

Tags: java, text, twitter, nlp

I am trying to build a sample app where in I want to parse a tweet and find the city name, 
country name and company name in that tweet.

The dumb way to do this can be maintaining list 
of names of country, city and company names and finding those in a tweet text but that 
approach will require change every time I want to add something new.

Is there a *library* which can parser a string and give me this information? Or can you suggest me a way that I should take?

Comment: Can you give a few examples of tweets that you would like to be able to parse using this method?

Answer (score 6):

[Enhancer](http://incubator.apache.org/stanbol/docs/trunk/enhancer.html) component of `Apache Stanbol` provides NER service with its RESTful API. You can simply give the tweet content to Stanbol and it gives you the enhancement i.e persons, places, organizations as enhancements.

You can try the demo servers:
http://dev.iks-project.eu:8081/engines
http://fise.demo.nuxeo.com/engines

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for Named Entity Recognition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the tweets all have the same structure and the information you want is not in a block text you could write a simple parser to get the information.